# Radio Button binding : Angular 5

Tags: html, angular, angularjs-directive

This code is basically for a MCQ with 4 options.I'm trying to increment counter(var) everytime the user selects and submits the correct answer using radio button.But the radio button binding isn't working somehow.
Tried googling on stackoverflow but the solutions provided didn't suffice.

**HTML:**

```
div *ngFor="let abc of questArrayNew1 ;let j = index" >

           {{j+1}}.{{abc.OP[j]}}

          <br>
        <input type="radio" name="s" [(ngModel)]="hello" [value]="abc.OP[j+1]" >{{abc.OP[j+1]}}

        <br>  
        <input type="radio" name="s" [(ngModel)]="hello" [value]="abc.OP[j+2 ]">{{abc.OP[j+2]}}

        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="s" [(ngModel)]="hello" [value]="abc.OP[j+3]">{{abc.OP[j+3]}}

        <br>
      <input type="radio" name="s" [(ngModel)]="hello" [value]="abc.OP[j+4]">{{abc.OP[j+4]}}

        <br>

          </div>'
<div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light" id="button1" (click)="submitAns(radio)">Submit</button>
</div>
```

**.TS:**

```
 submitAns(hello:string)
  {

  {
     if (hello == this.questArrayNew1[1]) //Checking if ans is right

    {
      console.log(hello); //undefined is being returned
      console.log(this.questArrayNew1); //this is returning perfect array
      this.counter++;

    }
    else
    { 

      console.log("Wrong answer");
    };

  } 

}
```

**JSON:**

```
[  
  {


    "OP":["The Government of India (GoI) has launched the web-based application e-FRRO scheme for foreigners. What does ‘FRRO’ stands for ?",
    "Foreigners Regional Registration Office" , 
    "Foreigners Registry Registration Office", 
    "Foreigners Reacceptance Registration Office", 
    "Foreigners Regaining Registration Office" ]

},

  {


        "OP":["QUES2","ADASD" , "ASDAD", "ASDASD", "ASDADS"]

    }


]
```

Comment: why are u passing "radio" variable in submitAns method ?

Comment: That fixed! Thanks .Now if I'm comparing the ans via use of  array index,it's not comparing rightly but with a string it does. Any idea why ?    `if (hello == this.questArrayNew1[1])`

Comment: please add your fixed in an answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This fixed :

```
<div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light" id="button1" (click)="submitAns(hello)">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're going to answer your own question the question should at least make sense. It's not even intelligible

Comment: I wasn't going to but apparently Mohammad asked me to add the fix  in an answer,so I did.Thankyou for your suggestion though.